# Ubuntu 18.04.1 random crashes and slow cpu

Tags: 18.04, cpu, crash

I have a MEDION AKOYA S6217T MD99051 Laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.1.

My Problem is, that it randomly (seems like it) crashes. Sometimes a few minutes after reboot, sometimes long after. With crash I mean totally so no Terminal session possible and no sysrq.
In syslog I couldn't find any useful information, just /00/00/00... at the point of crash.
In addition to that my cpu runs not at maximum frequency, often at minimum frequency (500MHz) even in performance mode, but sometimes id runs at max freq. as it should. The cpu temperature seems to be ok at around 60°C.

Could there be any connection between these problems?

If you need me to, I can provide more system Info.

Here is a plot of cpu temp and MHz I recorded. Every five seconds a value was stored. The two dips in temperature were times I suspended my Laptop for a while and at resume it was cooled down.

[image]

Comment: fresh install or upgrade?

Comment: If you mean upgrade from a lower Ubuntu version, no then it's a fresh install.